# SQL Server 2014 - Replica Server not available

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, clustering, availability-groups

I'm new to Sql Server and want to install SQL server alwayson clustering on my test environment. I followed the steps by [this site](http://www.derekseaman.com/2014/10/sql-2014-always-ag-pt-10-aag-setup.html):

On each node I can connect to SQL Server but why my 2nd node is not available so that I can add it as my 2ndary Replica?
According to this site, till "Always-On Availability Group Configuration" everything was successful.
p.s. It seems I cannot add my screenshot as I do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving the name of the other node, I gave the IP address of the other node. Then everything went well.
BUT what the reason was that it did not accept the name, I still do not know.